# Accessing identical named nodes at different levels in a general expression

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

My problem:

I have an xml source to convert into an Excel 2003 xml.

I have to adress nodes named identically at different levels:

```
root\tag1\tag2\tag3\**my_node**
root\tag1\tag2\tag3\tag3\**my_node**
root\tag1\tag2\tag3\tag3\tag3\tag3\**my_node**
```

Can I access my_node from a generic expression, no matter how many tag3 are preceding it?

Answer (score 0):

> Can I access my_node from a generic expression, no matter how many
>   tag3 are preceding it?

Yes, but it is expensive in terms of processing power:

```
//mynode
```

will select `mynode` anywhere in the document, and:

```
/root/tag1/tag2/tag3//my_node
```

will select any `my_node` that is a descendant of `tag3`.

Comment: this is ok. Next problem: how to select first value that is not null?

Comment: There is no "null" concept in XSLT. If you want the first element with a text node, add a *predicate* such as: `[text()][1]`.